# Implement a cleave function

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming

Think of cleave as the conceptual inverse of map. If map applies a function to each number in a list...

`map([1, 2, 3], x -> x * 5)` -> `[5, 10, 15]`

then cleave applies each function in a list to a number.

`cleave(5, [x -> x * 2, x -> x - 1, x -> x * x])` -> `[10, 4, 25]`

More formally, given:

- \$n\$, an integer, and
- \$L\$, a list of [black box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/standard-definitions-of-terms-within-specifications/13706#13706) with type signature `integer -> integer` or equivalent

Apply each function in \$L\$ to \$n\$, collecting the results in a list the same length as \$L\$. (It can be the same list if you want.)

### Challenge

Implement the cleave function in your language of choice.

### Format

You must accept an integer and a list of [black box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/standard-definitions-of-terms-within-specifications/13706#13706) and output a list of integers in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Argument order doesn't matter. The list of functions is flexible. You may accept:

- A list of black box functions (including a list of function pointers, etc.).
- A variable number of black box functions as parameters (varargs).
- A number indicating how many functions to accept.
- Etc.

### Rules

- Builtins are allowed, but please consider adding a less trivial answer so we can see how cleave might be implemented in your language.
- Explaining your answer(s) is encouraged!
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes (in each language) wins.

### Test cases

Note: for simplicity, instead of showing functions like `x -> 10 * x`, I will show them like `10x`. Imagine there is an \$f(x) =\$ in front of each of these.

```
  3, [] -> []
 42, [x] -> [42]
  0, [10x, x/2, abs(x), -x] -> [0, 0, 0, 0]
  8, [10x, x/2, abs(x), -x] -> [80, 4, 8, -8]
 -5, [abs(x), -x, x+10] -> [5, 5, 5]
  5, [abs(x), -x, x+10] -> [5, -5, 15]
 10, [x*x, x/10, x*x + 2x + 1, 13, x%3 - 3] -> [100, 1, 121, 13, -2]
950, [x*x, x/10, x*x + 2x + 1, 13, x%3 - 3] -> [902500, 95, 904401, 13, -1]
```

Comment: Husk 1 byter: `m`

Comment: I would love to see a Java solution to this question, which is fully object-oriented and wasn't totally meant for this....

Comment: @Wasif [done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230164/68942)

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, 11 bytes

`map.flip($)`

(If using Stack, this can be dropped to 7 bytes: `map.(&)`.)

Comment: Really is a shame `&` isn't there by default

Comment: `x#y=x<*>[y]` also works for same bytecount I think?

Comment: @Bubbler [As does `f x=map($x)`](https://tio.run/##rU/LDoIwELz7FXPw0KoYCpooid79hlpDAVEir1g0/XpxIVEveDCxh@l2dma3c9bmcszzNkUQQMPZQvYYqb6OFHXsptA1G1veFjorsUFSob5mZYMxUvhgUnVuuSOGTHQpPsL7fKQLDzJL1GDPhWQT4fIZWJhk99CjSkeGnq7Dhy2r3y3MWXJK@BIRTmnAsFZ0Xzp47/FMuEFA4XjH7C0ltROLKbweBbFxVZoGwqe@uUXNVccNfD5nYVElof9lzXr59z3tI05zfTKtE9f1Ew)

Comment: And `\x->map($x)`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda L,n:[g(n)for g in L]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUcFHJ88qOl0jTzMtv0ghXSEzT8En9n9OsYKtQjRURYWVgqGBVoWOAoJfoa9vhMzPTazQACrQrdBEFtWtiOXKAxpkwVVQlJlXopGmkVOso5CnqfkfAA)

Anonymous function that takes the list of functions and a number as arguments.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, 20 bytes

```javascript
a=>n=>a.map(f=>f(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7P1i5RLzexQCPN1i5NI09T839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRnSFgq2dQoWCloKRjgKUratgCGdrKVTEamqYAvUBAA) or [run all test cases](https://tio.run/##rZLBbsMgDIbvewpfJkELiU2IlBySN9gTVDnQrllbtUnVVBNvn0IXpmpUuzTIWJYx/4eBg/k2w@ayP19l139ux7Yau6o2zpKTObO2qlvWcT5u@m7oj9vk2H@xlgFknK0azuG1kaawat7@aGvltC1UNdhXCF5bq0gdMKgTLqyAH1CqpujDXHeJWQ/M8ikjn57Cq6OAyWJKMRulcAAtoBAgi4gj88B5Jhm4S8L/b9JzcgHe4lZmRUg3KYbQ76vYh@siDOHCwhLU3dOUoywsvmcgIfN4DyF0u1wRKe9ckYw@QZnPhytR5Z5YusZK1BoDlZrxBg) (courtesy of Arnauld)

Comment: [All test cases](https://tio.run/##rZLBbsMgDIbvewpfJkELiU2IlBzIG@wJqhxo16ytuqRaqom3z2ALUzWqXRpkLMvA/2HDyX7acfdxvFxlP7zup85M1jS9aWz2bi@sM03Hes6n3dCPw3mfnYc31jGAgrNNyzk8NvIcNu3TH22tvLYD04B7hBC0tUrUAaM64coJ@AHlao5e7PWQ2e3IHJ8z8u4tgjoKmC2lVItRKg/QAioBsko4soyce5KRuyb8v5OBUwoIlpayKEL6SSmEfl/F3bSLMIYrB2tQ357mHBVx8bkACUXABwihP@U3kQrOb5LJJ6jL5XA1qjIQa19YjVpjpFI7fQE)

Comment: @Arnauld, i think you accidentally switched the array and the number in the test cases

Comment: @EliteDaMyth Ah, yes. I was taking the parameters the other way around in my version and just pasted Shaggy's code without noticing.

Comment: Thanks, @Arnauld :) No way was I fiddling about on my phone to reformat all those!

Answer (score 7):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 22 bytes

```java
L->x->L.map(a->a.f(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVGxTsMwEJ3rr7jRqeIEmFBSLDGAhNRObSfEcE2d1CFxIvtSpUL99uBCqJAqRBf7/N47v2dfiXsUTatMuX0fdN02lqD0WNSRrqJpyi4wR1ZhfaLiGC7YvDMZ6caceKYNKZtjpuB5hGG2CmEt4YNN2m5T6QzWkPMVUJCyI2MjllXoHCxQm19CR0h@2zd6C7Wn@JKsNsXrG6AtXHBSTn5sZsuvkLPz@cUnKZQNYSykDOGSHLvOGumTKNwreBjmQvZCzqMaW45CYpTzPgiG1Jt@azzwaC0eXIRurh1x/rd5ALwHIeH2BqbQByFcoe0hhrv/pAukXZLgxl11pfAvGMfJfZXze7809gmzHV8eHKk6ajpKktb/M1XGj2hyZMfhEw)

-4 bytes thanks to Olivier Grégoire

`L` is a stream of `Function<Integer, Integer>` and `x` is an `int`. `Function` here is not `java.util.function.Function` but rather is a custom interface `Function<T, U>` with a single method `U f(T t)`. This is just to save bytes over the normal `Function<T, U>` which requires the method name `apply`, which is apparently allowed.

Comment: very nice. It was out of my expectation that java supports functions

Comment: Mmm reminds me of my own java

Comment: You can define your own interface `interface F { int f(int x); }` instead of `Function<Integer, Integer>`. Works the same, and you spare 5 bytes like this: `L->x->L.map(a->a.f(x))`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire oh, that's allowed? well, that's very clever - thanks

Comment: @hyper-neutrino That's one of the tools that we (Java golfers) use all the time. so yes, it's definitely allowed. Technically, in regards of golfing, what's the difference between an imported `Function<F,T>` interface and a customly defined `F` interface? Absolutely zero difference.

Comment: I would really like it when an answer contains some description of what kind of things it is using, when it's not a full program – especially if that's flexible in the question.
In the Java case, that could be the type of this expression (it could be a `Function<List<F>, IntFunction<List<Integer>>` with the definition of `F` given by @OlivierGrégoire). Or I guess Stream as you used in the TIO link.

Answer (score 6):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 9 bytes

```julia
a^b=a.|>b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzEuyTZRr8Yu6X9BUWZeSU6ehqlCnEJ0ha5dhZaRjgKI1jWE0FoVsZr/AQ)

## Julia 1.6+, 3 bytes

As pointed out by [@MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush), Julia 1.6 has since allowed defining `.|>` as a function, giving this 3-byter:

```julia
.|>
```

TIO does not offer Julia 1.6, but here's an interactive example:

```julia
julia> f=.|>
Base.Broadcast.BroadcastFunction(|>)
julia> println(f(5, [x->x*2, x->x-1, x->x*x]))
[10, 4, 25]
```

Comment: in Julia 1.6 `f=.|>` works, getting the answer down to 3 bytes

Comment: @MarcMush Thanks, I did not know about this feature!

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 23 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>b.Select(x=>x(a))
```

C# was born for this

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY4xC8IwEIV3f8XR6SJp1eogtA2IKCh1cnBuQ9RATaFJsSD@9hibwUWhHsfx7nF877gOuZYWtq3iqVSGepVLbdKP5wZjFHYb1d5EU5SVSHuLwdndQAa2yFjpOjqKSnCDXcY6LAixyWi0rpWuKxGdGmlELpVAbRqpLtG@lgoDCgF9U3BOUIk7fItG4ioZQuofwkVMEH7D4AHYEfciPP/jLodhx7Mp9WoSe3EozDValdot3gi7Ptq@AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
function(i,m)sapply(m,do.call,list(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLdioMwEIXvfYqB0kXbyTaJCvWi@yJLIalrQUh/ULfYp3cnpqabshftSpTxMOdzcmIzlKbSl2oz7L@PZVefjnGNh6TV57O5xgf8Or2X2hg0ddvFdZIMM5gaQZtat1UL@1MDXdV2sGuqS91d4Q1KoxuqItUverXx6D6hdxJDKVKCh5LgY9tKho0rGSm9a6lUG1uoSDEyKkZFvxQ87CbBMh7l1Sgv@qWkjsfZlpJuQQOl4TwpWeYpC9V@bqUocgnGKQKMMSUJPHPNgH3A53ayZxKdneJ5huDsmfQAPn1/jBPH@HDKC21SIdYByHVbHrT@F2hNjAyBzGztUSyfNvXbju60/tilQ5HJLk/J/UAvUuznxZ0juI944TZGfrz/DGjPHW8nTVzHEZxsgpa0Dzplds@8yDm@Tiy4zC20oPEKnmV8Aovt8AM)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 0 bytes

APL doesn't normally use lists of functions, but there are ways to use such. Even if the syntax for their creation is awkward, their use is simple: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT//v96htwqO@qX7Bh1aYPurd8qir6VHvGi6/aMNYvTSgVPWj3q2HpwOJWqCYEZLYdkMDkJAxVEgDpk5TQVtBwwjONAQpMoEqMjQG8UxhWoxrwIp0FYDCPkARP720////@ygYGnD5KFiaGgAA)

For the specific case of a list of integer↦integer functions, it is convenient to represent \$L\$ as a [train](https://apl.wiki/train), though it, despite appearances, isn't a list of functions. The calling syntax is identical to the above: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT//vY/CobYIOl48hiFKoftS7tZbLxwjIqTY0ODwdxIWIHt5uBGLVQBQY41cApHUhCk1AClHEIKq1DQ2AsqYgWZBeFHOAUkCmBkxcU0FbQcMIzjQESRoag5UY14AFdRWMa///B3pFwRjoEQUTI6ADFQyAliscWm8KooCEqYKhAYi0NDUAAA)

If we absolutely wanted something that took \$L\$ and \$n\$ and applied \$L\$ to \$n\$ using the above juxtaposition syntax, we write a full program which prompts first for \$\$ and then for \$L\$, applying \$L\$ to \$n\$ by juxtaposition of the input values:

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 bytes

```apl
⎕⎕
```

Each stylised console prompts for a value from the console (STDIN).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT//v96htwqO@qX7Bh1aYPurd8qir6VHvGi6/aMNYvTSgVPWj3q2HpwOJWqCYEZLYdkMDkJAxVEgDpk5TQVtBwwjONAQpMoEqMjQG8UxhWoxrwIp0FYDCPkARP700rkcd7QoF/4EOAqL/QM5/BTAo4DI04PLhgnEsTYE8AA)

Alternatively, we could define an "apply" operator that takes \$L\$ on the left and \$n\$ on the right:

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{⍺⍺⍵}
```

`⍺⍺` is the left [operand](https://apl.wiki/operand) and `⍵` is the right [argument](https://apl.wiki/argument).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVC9isJAGOzzFFsqGtmfbGFto7CkuNiJReDQRoitqI2ChRC5Kw5fwUKwUYQrkzfZF4nzZRPR4g7CzmS@mWTni@cz/3MRz5JpEdrdlz38hFF20ja92v3GpmcvHIlxZ4LR0qa3/IhjDU2@aHfBSVKV1Kh9TdZiDfmkgkxBZRKK3nQdUavS5DPIBkrYmXiGg7Q9IwjYsvyxkWWYu3s4Nb9LYitnUP8bgL4zBmR805y7RW2Mfitcfwcj0L8LYohiZHkpVCD7Wz63dZHQjtOD3W@xWyw5u@DC39h69NHDOewPosKwhAnuEXQ1kIMo7AEQSDQEQg0A2UU7AtBVSrvYAw)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because firstly I don't think it's fair to say there is a 0 byte solution here, as there isn't. It doesn't define a full program or function which performs the task. Also, I don't think using a train here is really in keeping with the actual question. The fact it happens to 'look' like a list in other languages is merely coincidence, might fool non APLers, but doesn't fool me!

Comment: @rak1507 I think the `L←N.f` part is valid, though the L0-5 variables aren't

Comment: I'm not convinced about that either. Is it *really* a list? The only way I think APL could truly have a list of functions would be to have a list of strings, or ⎕ORs

Comment: @rak1507 I discussed it with OP in the sandbox, and they wanted see this 0-byte approach, so I included it here, but also made sure to have actual program/function solutions included. Correct, trains are not lists of functions, which is why I included a link to their explanation. I wasn't trying to fool anyone. Anyway, I've now made it explicit that they are not lists of functions, and the "real" solution is the via-namespaces one, which is actually a real list of functions. I included trains because it was interesting and they had identical usage to the proper list approach.

Comment: I'm still not convinced that it is valid, ⎕NC 'L' is 3, so it's a function not a list of functions.

Comment: @rak1507 `⎕NC` is notoriously unreliable. It predates a lot of the language extensions, and there are a few things it doesn't know how to handle, like hybrids, fields, operands.

Comment: Ok, but ≢L doesn't work, ⊃L, etc, it's just not a list of functions. It may act conveniently similar to a list of functions, and it may be the best way to simulate a list of functions in real code, but for the purposes of this challenge imo it's not valid.

Comment: @rak1507 It really *is* a list of function (I have inside info about how the interpreter works), but since functions cannot take functions as arguments, `≢` and `⊃` don't work on them.

Comment: Hmm alright fair enough then.

Comment: This source code is only 5 characters but 11 bytes.

Comment: @maharvey67 Did you click the "bytes" link? Also, see [this (overwhelming) meta-consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each).

Answer (score 4):

## BQN, 7 bytes

```
{}¨⟜<
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=Q2xlYXZl4oaQe/CdlY7wnZWpfcKo4p+cPCAKYXJy4oaQLeKAvyvigL8oM+KKuCsp4oC/KOKMiuKImOKImikKYXJyIENsZWF2ZSAz)

-2 bytes from dzaima.

Takes a list of monadic BQN functions, returns a list of the same length.

Comment: Take \$L\$ as a train for 0 bytes :-)

Comment: Your `≍` function isn't an integer↦integer function.

Comment: i don't think there's a way to have a 0-byte function.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby 2.7, 19 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{b.map{_1[a]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6SS83saA63jA6Mba29n@BQlq0qU60rl1FdYWWUW1s7H8A)

Doesnt work on TIO cause of Numbered arguments.

Comment: wow, ninja'd by 11 seconds

Comment: @Razetime phew.

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 13 bytes

```
{@^f».($^n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2iEu7dBuPQ2VuDzN2v/FiZUKaRrRWoc26Sho6Rsa6ChUK6jEH9qkoK1gpKUSD6QMa4FihsZAUktBVcFYQVfBOFZHwdBA8z8A)

Comment: This language is insanity. It's like a code golfer wrote the sequel to Perl but wanted to include all of the other languages as well, and the result is beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) >= 4.1, 21 bytes

```r
\(l,i)Map(\(x)x(i),l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRydT0zexQAMuUKFZoZGpqZOj@T9NIyezuARFRkFbwVBHAUUkTsEITURLwVJTR8FE8z8A)

An anonymous function taking a list of functions and an integer and returning a list of integers.

TIO version uses `function` instead of `\` since TIO hasn’t been upgraded to R 4.1 yet.

Answer (score 4):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/j-uby), 3 Bytes

```
:-@
```

J-uby actually has a built-in for this, despite me never having actually used it. You are intended to use it with `-[f, g, h]` to create a function that will "cleave" a provided argument over the functions in the array. `:-@` is the symbol for unary minus in Ruby, which is callable in J-uby. It would take input in the form `:-@.call(L).call(n)`.

But built-ins are boring. How would it be implemented otherwise?

## 13 Bytes

```
~:*%(:& &~:^)
```

There are basically three components to this function. First is `~:*` which just creates a flipped-argument map function: `->(a, f){ a.map(&f) }`.

Next, there is `:& &~:^`. This defines the "n-applicator" function: given the input `n`, this defines a function that will apply `n` to whatever function you pass it. Essentially, it’s equivalent to `->(n){ ->(f){ f[n] } }`. How does this work? `^` is the function application operator, so `~:^` is function application with flipped arguments: `->(x, f){ f[x] }`. Since `&` is the partial application operator, `:& & ~:^` means you partially apply the flipped function application operator to the partial application operator. Anyone else getting semantic satiation?

Finally, we've got `%` in the middle. The `%` operator has different functionalities depending on its arguments, but in this case it denotes a "hook": given a binary function `F` and a unary function `G`, it returns a function that applies `G` to one of its two arguments before passing them on to `F`: `F % G == ->(L,n){ F[L, G[n]] }`. In this case, that means calling a flipped map (`~:*`) on the input array L and the n-applicator function (`:& & ~:^`).

The result is mapping the n-applicator function over the supplied array of functions, applying n to each element of the array. In plain Ruby, it's equivalent to `->(L,n){ L.map { |f| f[n] } }`

Comment: I've been looking at a lot of j-uby answers lately. Is there any sort of tutorial other than the docs in the README?

Comment: @Razetime The Readme is it. I might make a better tutorial some time if people are interested

Answer (score 4):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org), 14 bytes

```haskell
(|>)>>List.map
```

[`|>`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/Basics#(%7C%3E)) is  function application: `a |> f` means `f a`.

[`>>`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/Basics#(%3E%3E)) is function composition: `(f >> g) a` is `g (f a))`.

You can try it [here](https://elm-lang.org/try). Here is a full test program:

```haskell
import Html exposing (text)

f = (|>)>>List.map

main = 
  f 5 [\x -> x * 2, \x -> x - 1, \x -> x * x]
  |> Debug.toString
  |> text
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
v€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/sUdOa////KxkaHJ6uoqSjoHR4uxGYdgQRfkr/LQA)

Accepts a list of functions on the left in Jelly source code and the value on the right.

```
v€  Main Link; (x: functions, y: value)
 €  For each function in x
v   Evaluate it at y
```

Less trivial answer:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
³Ç$Ð¡Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef8xMMOXJCDDtzIkIEEgTiA0xq3/wrPDhyTDkMKh4biK////OP80)

Full program that accepts the blackbox-functions as a tied function in the header (standard for inputting blackbox-functions for Jelly), the initial value in the third argument (first value), and the number of functions in the fourth argument (second value).

```
³Ç$Ð¡Ḋ    Main Link; (x: value, y: number of functions)
   Ð¡     Collecting intermediate values, repeat y times:
  $       - last two:
³           - x
 Ç          - call the helper link (the blackbox)
     Ḋ    All but the first element
```

Basically, calls the black-box N times, where each time the function cycles its behavior (that's how tie works), and collects all N+1 results, then removes the initial value.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
S
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCI1XG7in6jOuzEwKjt8zrvCvTt8zrtOO3zOuzIqNSszLTvin6kiLCJTIiwiIiwiIl0=)

A full program that takes `number` then `functions`.

### Explained

```
S # Converts each function to a string. This involves evaluating them, which somehow takes input from the stack.
```

Takes input in the header because that's how to input functions

Answer (score 3):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 19 bytes

(-1 from [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230145/implement-a-cleave-function/230215?noredirect=1#comment547575_230215) by manipulating names and spacing on the original `fn n=>map(fn f=>f x)`.)

```ml
fn! =>map(fn f=>f!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBCoAgFAR/ZbtpVFDQ0e6dO0aEREagz6iHv28SER1n2ZnL2dJZ9hSDtljsqsMKFQ1lUJ3ThzAEozqTyecwQyGtEMe5E8OjJ67YD5xwkxBvoMWYPEoJUN4U@KCsf5DTJOMN)

Comment: 19 bytes: `fn$ =>map(fn f=>f$)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 7 bytes

```
Through
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PySjKL80PeN/QFFmXkm0sq5dWrRzfl5xSVFpcomDg3JsrFpdcHJiXl01V3V1rY6Cca0OkKGsBmSaGIHZhgbKajoKyvpGQNIxqThaORbI0AWrMCCkwAKsAFkQqFDb0AAkp2uKRxIip6wFMRkoBqS0lLWNgPJApqExkPDNT4lW1jGO1TUGaTA0IFWHpalBLVftfwA)

Built-in. Input `[L[n]]`.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 12 bytes

```
n#@n&/@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P@/9pIXKDnlq@g7Kav8DijLzSqKrlWt17dKilY1io5VjY9UcHByquaqra3UUjGt1gAxlNSDTxAjMNjRQVtNRUNY3ApKOScVA9UCGLliFASEFFmAFyIJAhdqGBiA5XVM8khA5ZS2IyUAxIKWlrG0ElAcyDY2BhG9@SrSyjnGsrjFIg6EBqTosTQ1quWr/AwA)

Input `[n][L]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 37 bytes

```
(d C(q((F N)(i F(c((h F)N)(C(t F)N))(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xDoMwEEP3foXHu650KkMHJEam/kAIV3FSEmhyqOLraWgnP8uWZdO0By3rcdCEjt5EPQYmRU@eaEbP1XVkP2A6KCxuQtAxu7zzhfwSoyTDc84ieG3Jmy6p3KHJZzmjFnELpmvYMe5oWpgUw2cWmyUjbXGsogVr1ih1sQPVQ3YOVHJxnBxoYNAVAxrmf/HBuDV8fAE)

#### Ungolfed/explanation

```
(load library)     Library contains ungolfed aliases for builtins
(def cleave        Define cleave to be
 (lambda (F N)     a function taking a list of functions F and a number N
  (if F            If F is nonempty:
   (cons             Construct a list
    ((head F) N)      whose head is the first function in F applied to N
    (cleave           and whose tail is the result of a recursive call
     (tail F)         with the remaining functions in F
     N))              and the same number N
   nil))))         Else, return empty list
```

Comment: shouldn't `(load library)` be a part of the bytes counted?

Comment: The actual solution doesn't use the library, just the test cases do.

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 49 bytes

```rs
|u,k:Vec<Box<_>>|k.iter().map(|z|z(u)).collect();
```

Maximally abusing [this ruling](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25156/should-rust-anonymous-functions-fully-specify-parameter-types). Would be nearly twice as long if all types where specified.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e2b006e3ff95c6dcada6a3bd089532c0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `combinators`, 6 bytes

```
cleave
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnJ@blJmXCBQpVrD@n5yTmliW@v8/AA)

Built-in.

Comment: Hm. I asked for a list and you gave me a stack full of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ṛĿⱮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8z3V4uqEBlweXI5cflzaQdWgT1@HtYFr74Y4ljxpmcBkac6kaxxv/f7hz9pH9jzau@394ub63ZuT//9HGOgrRsbFAwsQISBiCmQZADOQBpUx0FEzBQhaYQrqmIF1Ano6CGVgAnW8IMsdcRwGo11JHAcQzhJhvaYpVBgA)

Takes \$n\$ on the left and a list of link indices on the right.

```
  Ɱ    For each element of the right argument,
ṛĿ     call the link at that index monadically on the left argument.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 32 bytes

```
func[g n][forall g[g/1: g/1 n]g]
```

Modifies the list in place.
Doesn't work in `TIO`, but works fine in the Red GUI console:

[image]

Here's a `TIO`-compatible version:

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 41 bytes

```
func[L n][collect[foreach g L[keep g n]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxCoNAEAV7v@LVQooEbPwGq7TLK8LebhIiq1wU7u9PsdFuBobJlurTkrDxvvoaKgOCotM4mi7iU7aXfvDGID@zeYcgWT3@PeToC6WgxYM49Yb7VVsUspnzNxY4sqVVDfsCXd0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes the integer as input as a single digit array with the array of functions pre-assigned to variable `V`, outputs and array of single integer arrays.

```
V£mX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=CltAWCoyfSxAWC0xfSxAWCp4fV0&code=VqNtWA&input=WzVdCi1R)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>62</s> 52 bytes

```c
f(n,L)int(**L)();{while(*L)printf("%d ",(*L++)(n));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBDoIwEEXX9hQTjUkHwUSjq6onaNy5Mi60LdoEiyIoCeHsOEUxunBWM7/v/06roqNSTRNzF0q0LudBIJGjqB4nmxhOwyUjOeb9oYZ@SMJohNwhiroZWKeSQhtY3HJt0/FpxX6kxB68RnbQaXFIjOW@LxEqyExeZA5KCGAqoH5BRn0Iqi8ogkkH3a7FPvuTVHbQeW8dv6dWE8B8VvsyuZ3t0BsRlqT33kuFLeHLLxCy3vsK6tYbKdvTWnQx4Mg8f43@10CiYDVrng)

Takes `L` as a `NULL`-terminated array of pointers to functions taking an int and returning an int. Outputs results space-separated on stdout (with a trailing space).

-10 bytes from [@EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230145/implement-a-cleave-function/230223?noredirect=1#comment528265_230223)

(also [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 79 bytes with `#include<cstdio>` and ANSI function syntax. [Try it online! (C++)](https://tio.run/##hY5BDoIwEEX3nGKCMekUWGh0VfUE3ICwMAW0SR2aWpSEcHZsQRdudBaT/Jc/f740JrtIOU0rRVJ3VX2Qd1ep9hQ9WlVBwxQ5oNRvxnmOQSIOz6vSNfPaWA8aFq8riFMPkgQZIYpxCne3syIWchCGCPzMMXmxK5cgOL55mKKcf/XeC7Z2nSXogcNWwJj@NmWw@W/i0H@ZqNPaOLuAUXzqAflS@0U2jFLIUUTj9AI))

---

If writing to a caller-allocated array that is passed to the function is a valid form of output, then:

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>59</s> 51 bytes

```c
f(int n,int(**L)(),int*r){while(*L)*r++=(*L++)(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BTsMwDIbP61NYQ0hJ0yFgcMrGE1TcOJUKdUnKLJUU0nZUTHn24nTtgAM@JPaf358dtXpVahhKhrYFm9DJ4jjljIc0dvz4ucfKMJJiJ8SWEiE4s1z64QKtqjptYNO0Guur/UP0R6pwF7QA1nW3qwyOQ3oOR3Cm7ZyFHmK4leBPJqPODopfphXczKbmoyvcP6R@Nr0VaNmhRk2GKLDGb6XZXc5DI4ct6YtpqWR0hAgLJNFiGkHZ41Oajq9ezhiw1Hz/U6rKFAejs3V@0kpmE0iTWeeTWjtgDX6ZlxaQANeSrg2sJQiB85Ih3h1BS7a81M92eaZkmE8gH/lo@AY)

Same input as above, but outputs results through `r`, which must point to at least as many `int`s as `L` does `int(*)(int)`s (not including `L`'s `NULL` terminator).

-8 bytes from [@EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230145/implement-a-cleave-function/230223?noredirect=1#comment528265_230223)

(also [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes [Try it online! (C++)][TIO-kq6vpd7q])

Comment: You can save a lot of you drop C++ support, as C lets you do implicit int, K&R definitions, and empty parameter lists

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 43 bytes

I know there's already a nice JS entry, but I wanted to give it a go by giving both parameters to a single function. Different approach, same output.

Here's mine:

```js
(n,a)=>a.reduce((A,F)=>A.concat([F(n)]),[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcg9CoAwDEDhq2RMJBYUHCu4eInSIdQqirTiH719dRC3771FbjncPm9nGeLg86gzBhbSrajdD5fziB33b3fKxeDkRNNjIEtsLOV3HXH1ao0TjtiwSaBbSFBAzfC5hOp3AckS5Qc) Also [test cases](https://tio.run/##rZHPisMgEMbv@xRzWdBWEzUGkkMKvfS2TxBycNN0/1CS0qSLb58dtwqllr00Moh@jt9vHL/Njxnb89dp4v2w7@ZDNZOeGVptTHLu9pe2I2TLdrjfJu3Qt2Yi9Y70tKGsbuiM0jgcu@Q4fJADAcicSuG5kaZQNy931lqx2kK1AfsMwFlrFZmD8OZSrCyDKydVfvVmps/EvI/EUq/wh0U4c8HARwwploIU6K8Z@gEvIgzPPeaRY8Cupfi/jQ6TM3ARP2RJApYLMmbI8CP2plcoQhBhDepvll6TWTh8zYBD5uiOIQXewiSp3IRJPPr/Ml@MVgqVO2CJzyqF1iJAZTP/Ag) (modified from Arnauld's imlementation).

This is NOT memory friendly because I had to create a new array each time I used `Array.prototype.concat`. It would have been much nicer and  slightly shorter if JavaScript's `Array.prototype.push` would just return the modified array...

Answer (score 2):

## [Mlatu](https://github.com/mlatu-lang/mlatu), 20 bytes

```
->n;{n swap call}map
```

Explanation:
`->n;` pops off the stack and binds it to `n`. The list is left as the implicit parameter of `map` and is never bound. `{n swap call}` is a closure in Mlatu, which pushes `n` (the number) onto the stack, swaps the placement of the number and the function, and then calls the function with `n` as its argument. `map` takes the list and the closure and `map`s the list with the given closure.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html), 58 bits = 8 bytes

```
0000010110000000000101110011111011111100101111011010000010
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8pJ/v/fAAQMDQwNDeAAxANyDUEAQhpCBcHqDKGK/v8HAA)

It's a higher-order function that takes in a Church numeral and a list and returns a list. The list encoding is the one where a list is identified with its right fold function (e.g. `[1, 2]` would be `\c n. c 1 (c 2 n)`). (I'm using `\` as \$\lambda\$ in this answer.)

**“Readable” version:**

```
\\@@1\\\\@@2@46@@321\\1
```

Here, I'm using prefix notation. `\` is abstraction and `@` is application. Numbers are de Bruijin indices (starting at 1). Of course, (for example) `321` here means `3`, then `2`, then `1`, not the number `321`.

**Actually readable version:**

```
\k l. l (\a b c n. c (a k) (b c n)) (\c n. n)
```

### Explanation

Todo. It’s late and I’m tired.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 78 bytes

```go
func(x int,F[]func(int)int)(O[]int){for _,f:=range F{O=append(O,f(x))}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=xVTLToNAFN244ismTUxmdNBSWtOasHDTZeu-MWYKM5UIA8JAMIQvcdOY-FH1a5wHfcTQBW5ckHmdc--5c8_w8blJtrtZSvxXsqEgJiG3wjhNMgFuwIDFYnCyjIl4GVhWSTLgR5SUFHhfhWD2dLdgBfdhBUIu8Hz1pFdyjtQHl6snNdYsycAzZvdeRrjMNa-XHklTygO4xAxWCDVWRkWR8cZE_b4oxXtKAePAA6chrXY7l_syGTeSSBDscQslBDFem3jgqE7R97sVuAaLptHkvFj3JdsHclxEfclXB3IQln3Jt8fMSe-aLw9kP-H9yIpobuutIBndkzvLq0yOMKBcnAcaEFnnZyFyCh_WOWRRQsTdWNlE-sRSYO1WiEBtPWYSFnFoXAknWJmjlm2BI4RVb6GjRq26Qeg33jX4jpPxyBzpMjrOh8dMzlCmkM3UKWVFWNkC2g7qoE3_RrPbwk5hWPleRenA94Q7bTXmnowqLa-7MwYmGyKfkblqM3carKwFHfcsVdoWuhpuA7fpkDKb_KOW9vez3ZrxBw)

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 79 bytes, generic

```go
func f[T any](x T,F[]func(T)T)(O[]T){for _,f:=range F{O=append(O,f(x))}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=xVQxboMwFF06cQorUiW7gTaEpEorZeiSMXRgi1DlAG5RwVBjIiLECXqELlGlHio9TW0MSVSRgS4dkM33e__97__g4_M52e2HKfZe8XMAYhxSLYzThHFwDQYk5oOT1xjzl8FXzokx29skpx4gKwdgunVhARx9sXJlEDrIQdBeuQ4qScLAk07u5wxTkX5R2nOcpgH1oa0TWCBUaSzgOaOVSvt98b7BDHhRgDcBmIv8IeWupvFtGgBCZUQqiCASTxvORFxoU02TZOz7LW4JJJLQUomoYAEaehstwBAsq6omZ_m6L9k4kOM86ku-OpD9cNOXfHNUTnr3fHkgewntR5ZEdVtvOWZBS-5sr1AaoR9Qfh6oQHidnYWILXxYZ5BECea3E-kdYR6tdqF0LUSg1B6ZgEUUKv_AqS7NUYqxwDHS5WyhKde66gqh33hL4TtOJmN1VLfRcT46KpkjISGGWUuKjnRpC2iYqIM2-xvNaBo7henS9zJLB74n3Gy6UfekqqrL656MgomBiM9IXbXam5UurQVN6yxV2BZaNdwAVtVRyt30H2tp_km7nVp_AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 55 bytes

```lua
function g(L,n)for k,v in pairs(L)do print(v(n))end end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcs7DoAgEITh3lNsuWuo9BpcwvgKwQxmARvj2fFRqMU0/5dZclfKlNEnF0AzWwOZgpI3GznQ2jmNbGUItKpD4o0hMmKga9/PX1XHlBWEurmtei3@rX1s5t2beJhGygk)

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 19 bytes

```
L=>x=>[g(x)for g:L]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYs7DoAgEER7TkG5a@K3MiZ4Am5gLEBcYwMELLw9rh3VvDeTiSk8wRdSRav1Vet2wYsUkrwWvRcjlYRxaFDYn6YexcFgbBbuL9qRJ0GZeds5OxPj6R0YrMTWctTi@BzT7R8goIwwI5YP)

You might be wondering why I'm doing `fs.append` on each element. That's because making a list of functions errors when you try to print it or iterate through it - that's because it never becomes a list.

Observe [this](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@/8/UcFWQcPQQEuTKwnEMtLX5EoGMhKTirlSQAK6hkAprrRiEDtRRyFJRyFZRyEFKFRQlJlXopFWrGGhqfn/PwA) and notice that making a tuple of functions in Proton actually automatically cleaves.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 27 bytes

```perl
sub{$x=shift;map&$_($x),@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxdCoJAFIXfXYXITbS05iehEGE20ApEZAYcEirFMTBktt6UTpDU0z0f3zm3rbpLYkBmRt3FCEOmzrXs0ytvfSgDGMKIldqksumAB47r5rSIprMn0TR4S8uHGTFaQ5mjQs80xx2xwIVaqNhmuz0m6Nv/f4CR/tUb8rnYKkwXlRWNqS6ccGQi80EGDHiYKv7wmPC0eTZtXzc3ZeJTskX4BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 14 bytes

```scala
x=>_.map(_(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zQcmYK1uSGqclNwJSGLkdA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
4 :'x`:0 y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcaxCsIwFEDRPV9xcYmNSUhLszzUQcFJHFxLIVJSRAQ3iV8fFcThwLnVhdczG0FjCciH8@zPx0PtEV2SBF66Nuq080z3fHnmZbQMBbelYOgsvzva/w1lbL4d2mDpLV0clcrT9cFK0lqSEWYi9Q0)

Called like:

```
+:`<:`*: f 5
```

In J, you cannot pass around a list "functions" (aka "verbs") directly, but you can pass around a list of "gerunds", which, like English gerunds, are noun-ified verbs.

Then you can use the ["Evoke Gerund"](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/graveco) conjunction, specifically the  `` `:0 `` form of it, to call those gerunds as verbs again.

Doing this requires (afaik) an explicit verb, because conjunctions can only apply to a literal or a named variable.  Here, the default LHS variable `x` represents the list of gerunds we are "evoking", and the integer we are applying them to is `y`.

### worth noting

This would be a very un-J thing to do, and if you wanted to solve this specific problem the natural solution would be to create a train like this:

```
+:,<:,*:
```

which creates a *single new verb*, rather than a list of verbs, but will produce the same output as the submission above when applied to `5`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
@Z{bM[a]}
```

A function that takes a number and a list of functions and returns a list of results. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@K/x3yGqOsk3OjG29r@CKZdCdLyWkXW8rqF1vFZ8LJfm//@6BQA)

#### Explanation

The `M`ap operator has a built-in ability to take a list of functions as its left argument. Unfortunately, it still expects the right argument to be a list of values, so we have to do some boxing and unboxing:

```
  {     }  Anonymous function
   bM        Map (each function in) the second argument
     [a]     to a list containing the first argument
           The result is a list of single-element lists
 Z         Zip: now we have a list containing a single list
@          Get the first (and only) element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Squire](https://github.com/sampersand/squire) (commit `a380c1f`), 53 bytes

```php
journey f(n,a){i=N whilst(t=a[i=i+I])!=ni{a[i]=t(n)}}
```

Thou shalt call `f` like so:

```php
# Example journeys
journey mul(n)
{
    reward n * II
}
journey sub(n)
{
    reward n - I
}
journey squ(n)
{
    reward n * n
}
# Createth a quest of journeys
quest = [ mul, sub, squ ]
# Number to cleave (thou might also use V directly)
n = V
# Embark on journey f
# f modifieth array in place.
f(n, array)
# Useth how thy wishes
# Array(Number(10), Number(4), Number(25))
dump(array)
```

##### Ungolfeth:

```php
# Createth a journey named "cleave"
# It accepteth 2 arguments.
journey cleave(n, array)
{
    # Defineth a counter variable i with the mere value N.
    # Arrays are I-indexed; but we want to increment as we do things.
    counter = N
    # Alas, Squire doth not yet supporteth embarking directly
    # on journeys in arrays, so we musteth hire a mercenary.

    # Useth a property that going outside of an array's
    # kingdom will reward naught but ni ("null"). 
    whilst (mercenary = array[i = i + I]) != ni
    {
        # Embark the mercenary on his journey and
        # overwriteth array[i] with its reward.
        array[i] = mercenary(n)
    }
}
```

Note: I am trying to find a way to embed Squire on TIO, without much luck. It comes too close to the character limit to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```
{n,L->L*.call(n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZLRCoIwFIbve4pzE6htts0JeqFPUE8QXSyRuhAFlSjEZ7ez0pxKV0Vw3NjOv@//mTuXRXG9d0mWqmsadU1OdjTeOW6isszK7bZTVZWWNbwElkfgcLQhinBaTVtSYK@BG9AYh7ZXSTHXsVHGGThaS@B9bgvCWO9VfXHVqbJutrFLRzzC@prbBL@0CdBBEkAmDeZG1B@dPoMM740ONJDxsK459FumDsUXVM7MX7S8E80wNpwnWPQzN3rcmwjX4AHFbwjAGRpxLKEHfDN08QpC/09ZQiZ8HSfEGwmZlGyIxI/dAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 21 bytes

```
[ [ call ] with map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVE9b8IwEN3zK95clEKSRmpBZa26dEGdogzGGIjyYeNzFCHEb08vDinq1kr1cHfv3Xunk28vpNO2/9y8f7wtIYi0JJTKNqpCLdwRpE6taqQiGFHY0GpZKgdjlXNnY4vGYRUElwDDS/C6xgVXj57iEWXIbwwWExMt8MB0hnjuk9iSz4063NXPf1GH6aT@2fXu2X3o72TR96Z0mrrzwle71gwkdcIg5r0its3GjtUGUeLrBLXecQynkS/p/4689hlzUlQVw67gQ9Xsznv@/fGK6wGTE7J87L8A)

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 12 bytes

```
cleave>array
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVFNT8MwDL33V7wzU7e1ZRIfole0yy4Tp2oHLwtQdWmCHZimab@9pCll4gYSPsT2e89PVvxMylvuntbL1eMdlDXbuqWAyFQMsUejudV7kIhVAkP@FY5qTtmqRns41t4fHdetx32SnBL0UeChxAnn2F3nQ1dh84VgPiLZHFcBrpDPYqKtxNzql4v65i/qdDGqf7JxenIx/Z0s@95U3kZ2Vsdq9@56UA7kkIe9sjA2GRi2DlkR6wLG7sKbjpa3i/@1PKPq1F7Thy6JmY7dpv/44V6lCUbiSTXT7hM)

Builtin.

Answer (score 1):

### Python2, 21 bytes

```python
print[f(n)for f in l]
```

Makes use of Python 2's `print` being a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 17 bytes

```clj
#(for[f %&](f %))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVHbaoQwEH3PVxxYLEnXsEmMoBT6B/2CkAdbDbVYdV0L7tfbSVcp9GkfCpPMzOGcuSRv3fDxNTUrr5uAsB54GCYXkDx4TrcQq2C8Hi7NGQ6LYy7zT5DPcJ45a9DWTT@383UDrSFY4cAfoRWpKTohgYnBSzW/n6rXS4TlxlcpNiNdcb@uIIlNUaSQBSll/pdH@fFWalPkKaIR@S6upKMjW9@2SX6H0kr8KHaUvIleUxh6t3joLDIk@NR8EoeybC@tFU2uyUy8MmoUX6zM/7dLqUweG5W0RamsVXsz7Zn3jI9T289dD16NY3dFwCLoo78B)

Takes input as varargs where the first argument is the integer, and the rest are functions.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
€.V
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdMavbD//6OV8pR0lEL0gYRLXvGh7dp2QJahMZAwVjXWVYrlsjQ1AAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCqHrE4TX/HzWt0Qv7r/M/Ojpa6dB2JR0lGyDOU4rVMY3VUYiOjtUxBtNKQBETIwjT0EALqMYaiA@3AAkNoJQBThkLiAyUrwNUog0U1TXFKgwVzQMKhOgDCZe84kPbte1A8sZAwljVWBeoytCAKGWWpgaxsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
€    # Map over each function-string in the first (implicit) input-list:
 .V  #  Evaluate it as 05AB1E code, with the second (implicit) input-integer as argument
     # (and output the resulting list of values implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```lisp
(\(N)(p m(\(F)(F N
```

An anonymous function that takes its arguments curried: calling it on an integer returns a second function, and then calling that on a list of functions performs the cleaving.

You can try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/tinylisp2). Example session:

```lisp
tl2> (\(N)(p m(\(F)(F N
(() (N) (p m (\ (F) (F N))))
tl2> (def cleave _)
cleave
tl2> ((cleave 4) (list inc dec square))
(5 3 16)
```

#### Explanation

The lexical scoping of tinylisp 2 makes this solution much simpler than [my tinylisp solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230322/16766).

```lisp
(\(N)(p m(\(F)(F N))))
(\                   ) ; Lambda function
  (N)                  ; that takes an integer N:
     (p m           )  ;  Partially apply the map function to
         (\        )   ;  another lambda function
           (F)         ;  that takes a function F:
              (F N)    ;   Call F on N
```

The return value is a function that takes a list and maps the inner lambda over it. Calling this on a list of functions gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 11 bytes

```
:^⍏&[#0 ⊙⍧]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMEyjZTUNIWSpaUlaboWG63iHvX2q0UrGyg86pr5qHd5LER8vyaXRma-VXlRZklqTp6CRomCKZDITFXQVcjJ09TUhKhasABCAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 20 bytes

```
$[n a][map a'f->f n]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?C7z4cY)

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 68 bytes

```
r1l2(?\$:' '=?/$:@2p1+10.
/$i   /
\
\$~{~r
>l ?\;/0.
\oan/ \e@':$'~\
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoicjFsMig/XFwkOicgJz0/LyQ6QDJwMSsxMC5cbi8kaSAgIC9cblxcXG5cXCR+e35yXG4+bCA/XFw7LzAuXG5cXG9hbi8gXFxlQCc6JCd+XFwiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjUiLCJzdGFjayI6IiA6KyAxLSA6KiA6fiBhLCIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

(Assuming leading space is acceptable in input. See [this](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoicicgJzFsMig/XFwkOicgJz0/LyQ6QDJwMSs0MC5cbi8kaSAgICAgIC9cblxcXG5cXCR+e35yXG4+bCA/XFw7Ly5cblxcb2FuLyBcXDArM2VAJzokJ35cXCIsImlucHV0IjoiNSIsInN0YWNrIjoiOisgMS0gOiogOn4gYSwiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==) for 76 bytes if not.)

Well this is challenging. My strategy for accepting a list of functions is to parse them from input separated by spaces, then write them to the source code along with some piping to preserve the input number. Then I push the input number to the stack and send the instruction pointer to the third row which is where the functions are written. Then I clean up some garbage values and output the result.